# Using the normal distribution to approximate the binomial distribution (weird example)

Tags: normal-distribution

The problem: *suppose 406 dice are rolled.  Find the probability of getting exactly 100 5s.*

Binomial definitely applies, since there is a fixed number of trials (406 dice) and there are two distinct outcomes (rolling a 5 = success, not rolling a 5 = failure).  Let $X$ be the number of 5s showing, then we are approximating $P(X = 100)$.

First, $n \cdot p \approx 67.7 \geq 5$ and $n \cdot q \approx 338.3 \geq 5$, so it looks like normal can be used.  Also, $\mu = n \cdot p \approx 67.5$ and $\sigma = \sqrt{n \cdot p \cdot q} \approx 7.5$, furthermore the random variable $X$ (number of 5s showing) can by made continuous by writing it as an interval: $99.5 < X < 100.5$

Now set up the problem and use tables:

$P(X = 100) \approx P(99.5 < X < 100.5) = P(4.26 < z < 4.4) = 1 - 1 = 0$

Getting exactly 100 5s is a very unlikely event, so this makes sense to me, but the class notes uploaded by our teacher show a different answer (0.00715).

Comment: @StatGuy The exact number is a rational number whose denominator has 315 digits. A numerical estimate is nontrivial, while a normal table is easy to come by.

Comment: My understanding is that since $p$ is not close to $0.5$, the approximation is very inaccurate, is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Although the probability you get from the normal distribution is very small, it isn't zero:
$$P(4.26 < z < 4.4) \approx 5\times10^{-6}$$
That said, the probability can also be calculated exactly from the binomial distribution:
$$
P(100) = \binom{406}{100}\frac{5^{306}}{6^{406}}\approx 11 \times 10^{-6}
$$
which can be estimated from Stirling's approximation $n!\approx (n/e)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$ and a good log table. The normal approximation gets the right order of magnitude, but it's still a factor of 2 off.

What I'm not sure of is where the value $0.00715$ comes from. Are you sure you're looking at the right answer?